# how to handle a final_act function call which can throw?

Tags: c++

I need to put in a call to a function, which can throw, at the end of every call to the client code.
The idea is to put the function call in a destructor following RAII.
I have gone through final_act, scope_exit, boost_scope_exit, but unclear how to handle it.
The catch is the function can throw, and the program should also not terminate.
How do I handle this.
No answers are clear on stackflow on this question.

Design question so N/A

Comment: if the function throws do you still want your call to your function?

Comment: Unfortunately it is legacy code, and the function might throw.

Comment: How was it handled before in this legacy code? Was it called only if the scope was existed successfully? You can detect successful scope exit since c++17, and mark your guard's destructor `noexecpt(false)` regardless.